# How to display list of audio files and play when particular file is selected and also want to show the audio player during playing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am very new to iPhone development and want to develop a view in my application in which,
as the view will open the list of audio files will display and when it will select to play
it should be play with showing audio-player on screen.

Comment: We're not an application writing service.  Is there something specific you're having a problem with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Tableview for displaying list of audio files.AVAudioPlayer is used to play the audio.Before that you should refer this link ,
[AVAudioPlayer class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) which will help you to start further.

Hereafter, post your question more specifically..

Regards

Renuga